# Wordpress ignore page breaks on load

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I tried this question over at wordpress support and got no response. I have a page that has page breaks within it (`<!-- nextpage -->`) to split the content into multiple pages. I'm looking to remove the page breaks before load when certain sources hit the page, ideally using PHP. My thought process was that i could use the query string

http://example.com/post/?source=example

as an indicator for whether the page breaks will be there or not. But my question is whether it's actually possible to remove the page breaks that late? Considering the DOM is already loading when the php is executing but it hasn't reached the content, i'd assume not but i'd love to get the feature in.

Chris

Comment: _“Considering the DOM is already loading when the php is executing”_ – nope, PHP gets executed first. Only after the script sends its output to the client, the latter can start building the DOM.

Comment: I see, so considering the php is executed first. In wordpress it just uses a function get_content() (or something like that) to gather the information from the post. Would it be possible to manipulate the information being passed through the function without altering the actually post?

Comment: Wordpress has a lot of “filters”, that you can use to modify all sorts of content, database queries etc. Maybe this can help: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/183582/how-to-ignore-or-disable-nextpage-tag

Answer (score 0):

First get the query var.
use wp_link_pages() as a conditional function in the page.
It will be executed only if you have (or may be don't have) certain query var in the url

Answer (score 0):

```
add_action( 'the_post', function( $post )
{
    if (false !== strpos( $post->post_content, '<!--nextpage-->')) 
    {
        // Reset the global $pages:
        $GLOBALS['pages'] = [$post->post_content];

        // Reset the global $numpages:
        $GLOBALS['numpages']  = 0;

        // Reset the global $multipage:
        $GLOBALS['multipage'] = false;
    }
}, 99 );
```

Esta acción verificar en el contenido de cada articulo si existe `<!--nextpage-->` y establece las variables globales de WordPress como un articulo **NO MULTIPAGE**

Comment: Could you please give a reason as to why this works? Whilst providing working code is a great way to answer the question, some background information about how the code achieves what OP was looking for might be helpful in their understanding of your answer.